# Add a ngModel after the div is instantiated

Tags: angular

I am doing something kind of complicated, and I can't provide a stackblitz of the situation.

Using angular 4, is it possible to add a ngModel dynamically via another component ?

Explanation :

I am using 2 external library, one for dragging and drop, one for virtual scrolling. the content that is draggable is the dynamically loaded content in the virtual scroll. The problem I have is, my drag library expect me to add `[(aBinding)]` on the div just above my draggable elements. But, my virtual scrolling div, create some div in the middle and I can't do this :

ex on template ;

```
<virtualscroll> <!-- I should add the model here -->
<items ngFor"let item of items"></items>
<virtualscroll>
```

ex when builded and run ;

```
<virtualscroll> <!-- but when on run, this is not anymore the div just above my items -->
    <div>
       <div>
        <items ngFor"let item of items"></items>
       </div>
    </div>
 <virtualscroll>
```

what I would like =>

```
<virtualscroll> 
    <div>
       <div><!-- add ngModel here to this component generated div-->
        <items ngFor"let item of items"></items>
       </div>
    </div>
 <virtualscroll>
```

But, since that div is made by a library, I can't do it via template.

I was wondering if is possible to add a binding on a div after the template has been build and showed on the page

Comment: So you really need the 2-way data binding?   what functionionality do you want to achieve?   this is another / similar question i have worked on today (which deals with additional divs being added).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016938/ng2-dragula-with-a-virtual-scroll/55017783#55017783.  However I think the main question is how you want to get data and what interactions you need (other than those of the already included in the libraries)

Comment: the question you linked is interesting, I will look into it. Basically, I just want the double data binding so that, when the scroller get new data, he will update the model, and the model, will update the drag and drop directive. right now, I can not achieve the latter part

Comment: I think it might be hard to achieve this out of the box, but I might be wrong.  Getting the data to display is simple, but if I understand correctly you also want the drag-drop changes (and general changes to data in the front-end) to be persisted back to the source. A solution based on RxJS / Observables / Subjects / ... might be the easiest way.